# SP DataTimeControl validation issue (error message does not disappear after choosing correct date)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, asp.net, validation

I write simple WebPart with few asp.net controls.
I have problem with validation control and SharePoint date time control. 
The markup:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtc" runat="server" DateOnly="true" HoursMode24="true" OnDateChanged="dtc_DateChanged"/>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="valDtc" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="dtc$dtcDate"
            Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck"  ErrorMessage="choose or write correct date (YYYY-MM-DD)">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
```

If I write some wrong date I have error message, if I write correct date message disappear. But after I choose other (correct) date from calendar the error massage does not disappear (but should).
How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

Trying to use SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator:

```
<SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator ID="ifval" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="dtc"
            Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" EnableClientScript="true"  ErrorMessage="choose or write correct date (YYYY-MM-DD)">
            </SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator>
```

gives me error:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'dtc' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'ifval' cannot be validated.]
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String name, String propertyName) +11200546
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +50
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +72
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.get_PropertiesValid() +44
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +38
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.InputFormCompareValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +131
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
```

if I change ControlToValidate="dtc" to "dtc$dtcDate" it behaves the same as CompareValidator and error message does not disappear after choosing good date.

(I move question from stackoverflow cause no one answer it there)

[image: Picture:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue - when I select the correct date from calendar, the validation control does not update its state.
I found the solution using the JavaScript and overriding the OnPickerFinish method..

Content part of the page:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="MyDateTimeControl" runat="server" DateOnly="true" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="MyDateTimeControlCompareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MyDateTimeControl$MyDateTimeControlDate" 
Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date." />
```

JavaScript part:

```
function OnPickerFinish(resultField) {
clickDatePicker(null, '', '');
// Ensuring that we are addressing the right DateTime control:
if (resultField.id == '<%= MyDateTimeControl.Controls[0].ClientID %>') {
    var valatorCtrl= document.getElementById('<%=MyDateTimeControlCompareValidator.ClientID%>');
    if (valatorCtrl != undefined && valatorCtrl.isvalid == false) {
        ValidatorEnable(valatorCtrl);
    }
}}
```

I made this solution on the basis of several articles from the Internet. But the main was this: http://www.meritsolutions.com/microsoft-sharepoint/managing-sharepointdatetime-control-events-from-client-side/